# How to extract sentences of text that contain keywords in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to return all sentences that contain 'any' words in a list, but the result only returns the sentence for the second word in the list. In the example below, I wanted to extract the sentence that contained inflation and commodity, not just commodity. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
text = 'inflation is very high. commodity prices are rising a lot. this is an extra sentence'
words = ['inflation', 'commodity']
for word in words:
    [words.casefold() for words in words] #to ignore cases in text

def extract_word(text):

    return [sentence for sentence in text.split('.') if word in sentence]

extract_word(text)

[' commodity prices are rising a lot']
```

Comment: Please read the following an provide a full [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `if word in sentence` will check if the iterator `word` from the `for` loop is in `sentence`. Since `"commodity"` is the last  element in the list `words`, after the `for` loop, `word` will contain the string `"commodity"`.

Instead, in the list comprehension statement, you can check if any of the elements in `words` is in `sentence`, such as below:

```py
text = 'inflation is very high. commodity prices are rising a lot. this is an extra sentence'
words = ['inflation', 'commodity']
sentences = [
    sentence for sentence in text.split(".") if any(
        w.lower() in sentence.lower() for w in words
    )
]

print(sentences)
# >>> ['inflation is very high', ' commodity prices are rising a lot']
```

Answer (score 2):

I find generators to be pretty handy in these kinds of cases.

```
def extract_word(text):
    words = ['inflation', 'commodity']
    sentences = text.split('.')
    for sentence in sentences:
        if any(word in sentence for word in words):
            yield sentence

>>> list(extract_word('inflation is very high. commodity prices are rising a lot. this is an extra sentence'))
['inflation is very high', ' commodity prices are rising a lot']
```

It's readable and easy to understand what the outcome is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
texts = ' commodity prices are rising a lot. some random text. this text contains the word: inflation'
words = ['inflation','commodity']
lst_words = [words.casefold() for words in words] #to ignore cases in text

def found_word(sentence, lst_words):
    return any(word in lst_words for word in sentence.split())

def extract_word(text):
    lst_sentences = []
    for sentence in text.split('.'):
        if found_word(sentence, lst_words):
            lst_sentences.append([sentence + '.'])
    return lst_sentences

extract_word(texts)
# [[' commodity prices are rising a lot.'],
#  [' this text contains the word: inflation.']]
```

It is a bit longer, but I think much better to read.

Comment: It's unnecessary to create a list in `any(...)`. The `any()` function takes a generator. Asking it to create a list forces one full iteration on the generator to create the list, and another iteration on the list to evaluate `any()`.